# Date Picker ( Month and Year ) - Which will give a better User Experience (Suggest)?

Tags: mobile, interaction-design, android, ux-designer, human-interface-guideline

I am currently working on a mobile app and in one screen user requires to enter month and year.

I would like to know which one will be better in terms of ux.

[image: DATE PICKER]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go Year/Month instead of Month/Year. You should start by Year, and then move to Month and then finally move to Day. Because Years come first, and it is easier.

I'd suggest Year-Month layout and format. Looks nice.

**Edit 1: For the sake of simplicity, the first one is better.**

Comment: I don't agree with the year-month order. It's currently "april 29th, 2017", so month-year would be logical.

Comment: @NGAFD: The best approach for search and for selecting, is Year and then Month. Just think about it. "The year-month-day order, such as the ISO 8601 "YYYY-MM-DD" notation is popular in computer applications because it reduces the amount of code needed to resolve and compute dates."

Comment: Solid point. I agree.

Comment: Strongly disagree. "Because it reduces the amount of code" is never a valid reason for a UX decision. It should rather be based on user expectations. (That is: month-year, but wasn't the question anyway. )

Comment: @not2savvy, user expectation is usually speed. Of course depending on the context, and user group. This was never specified.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree again. While speed is one aspect, another important requirement is "Don't make me think", meaning the UI should use common standards. And BTW, unexpected widgets or workflows reduce a user's speed significantly.

Comment: End users naturally think of dates in month day year, or day month year format, so why force them to think otherwise? Not that it matters, but what is the month year data being used for?

Comment: I don't agree with this at all. I worked for the largest hotel company in the world and worked on the search team and we found that "Mon, Apr 14, 2016" was the most effective way of displaying a date because naturally that's how people remembered days.

Comment: also that will be different per country

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about the design of the two alternatives, choose the one which fits best with the expectations of your users. Things to consider here:

- The first design is more consistent with "standard" iOS pickers. So
  design 1 is probably most familiar/ easy to use for most users.
- Does your app have any other pickers in other places? Which of these
  two designs is most consistent with these other pickers? Pick the
  design which is the most consistent with the rest of your app.
- Design nr 2 seems to indicate that currently the month-picker is
  selected (it is bigger). And that this may have some functionality.
  Design nr 1 (or the standard iOS picker) does not have this
  functionality.

If it is about month-year versus year-month (as in the other answer + comments), I would advise to go with the expectations of the actual users of your app, in this particular situation.

E.g. if the picker is used to enter the expiry date of a credit card, then (at least in my part of the globe), month-year is better, because that is the order that credit card companies put it on the cards.
As a matter of fact, displaying the months in '01', '02', '03' etcetera,  may even be better, because on some credit cards that is how the expiry date is displayed there.